# Extracting transfer function from output measurement

Tags: noise, transfer-function

Let's say I am generating pure sine oscillations with a laboratory instrument on which vibration frequency and amplitude are tunable (there are uncertainties +/- 1 % with my inputs), and I get my output data from accelerometers (also with white noise).

The question is how can I estimate the transfer function of the aforementioned instrument from measured data ?
Doing FFT and amplitude estimation from the output will provide information, but how can I take into account noises and uncertainties ?

PS: My data acquisition frequency is always 10 times higher than input frequency.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86575/63763) (and [this similar one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86489/63763)) and let me know if that answers your question. It gives details on transfer function estimation when there is noise in the input and the output. [This reference](https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/transfer-function/) also has some useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and links ! DSP is new to me so mostly the linked [reference](https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/transfer-function/) helps me the most to understand what is going on.  May be a final question : since I assume there is uncertainties (not noise) with my input and noise with my output, can I assume as input (time series of) a pure sine function ? and then calculate directly the H_1 estimate ? Thank you again for your help